# What is the correct way to forward ng-model to an element inside your directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a directive that uses the compile function to replace the element. The template that replaces the element has an input which I want to apply ng-model to. The ng-model attribute should be applied to the original element.

I have it working-ish, but when typing into the input in my directive the model updates lag behind. The updates appear instant if typing into a standard input with ng-model.

I'm not sure I'm describing this well enough... So here's some code:

Here's the html

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-model="test" model-forwarder></div>
  <input ng-model="test" type="text" />    
</div>
```

Here's the js

```
angular
.module('app', [])
.directive('modelForwarder', function(){
    return {
        require: '^ngModel',
        compile: function(element, attributes){
            element.replaceWith('<div><input type="text" /></div>');

            return function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel){
              var input = element.find('input');  

                ngModel.$render = function () {
                    if (ngModel.$viewValue !== undefined)
                        input.val(ngModel.$viewValue);
                };

                input.bind('keyup keydown keypress blur change', function (e) {
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        var value = input.val();
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                    });
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KjNL2/

My question is, "**Is there a better way of doing this? Am I doing something wrong?**"

Answer (score 3):

Try to two-way bind the `ngModel` into isolated scope of your directive.

http://jsfiddle.net/bateast/RJmhB/1/

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="test">
    <my-dir ng-model="test"></my-dir>
    <input type="text" ng-model="test"/>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('test', [])
    .directive('myDir', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '='
            },
            template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="ngModel"></div>',            
        };
    });
```